# Jenkins multijob condition to run job

Tags: jenkins, multiprocessing

Can anyone hint me how to pass parameter with yes\no values as a condition to lun specific jobs in multirun job?

Lets assume, that I have multijob "Masterjob" with 2 parameters - "run job Terminal_deployment" (with values "YES" or "NO") and "run job TVSignage" (with values "YES" or "NO"). How to pass this values to condition parameter to run or skip specific job in multirun job? Can anyone give me an example?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, how to write conditions to run downstream job, if yes selected:

```
"${Terminal}" == "YES"
"${TV_SIGNAGE}" == "YES"
```

to run "Terminal" or "TV SIGNAGE" jobs.